# Send java email without authentication/with out sender password

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send `java` email without senders password. Below you can see the code. I change `mail.smtp.auth` from `true` to `false`. There is a override method which method name `getPasswordAuthentication()`:

```
public class SendMailUtilNineThirty implements Runnable {

    final private String SMTP_SERVER = "192.186.16.14";
    final private String SMTP_PORT = "135";
    final private String TO_EMAIL = "saman@thal.com";
    final private String TO_EMAIL = "dumidu@thal.com";
    final private String FROM_EMAIL = "samanchandana@thal.com";
    final private String FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD = "1qaz2wsx@";

public void sendEmail(String emailContent, String subject) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
            Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_EMAIL, FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD);
                }
            });

            mailSession.setDebug(true);
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM_EMAIL));
            message.addHeader("site", "thal.com");
            message.addHeader("service", "Thal Service");
            message.setSentDate(new Date());
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(TO_EMAIL));
            message.setSubject(subject);
```

How to send email without password authentication? Thanks.

Comment: why would that be possible?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Is it because of JavaMail version. My JavaMail version is 1.4.6

Comment: Use the session without an Authenticator: Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);

Comment: @vasquez Not working

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 452 (IP, Sender) first encounter.

Comment: The remote smtp server tells you that the sender address or your ip address is not accepted. Has nothing to do with JavaMail.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to authenticate to the mail server.  If you run your own mail server, you may be able to set it up so that it doesn't require authentication, but none of the public email service vendors is going to allow that, for what I hope are obvious reasons.